# Firestore cloud function working on emulator as expected but not after deployment on firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

My cloud function is working perfectly on firebase emulator although after deploying into firestore, it doesn't work. The function executes although nothing happens.

It was working in firestore before introducing the if statement for statusValue. Although, even after the introduction of the if statement, it is still working as expected in the emulator.

I've deleted and redeployed the functions and installed the latest version of node with no success.

Appreciate the help!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// capture group members when a new message is added to a group to notify them
exports.newMessage = functions.region('australia-southeast1')
.firestore
.document('ChatRooms/{chatRoomsID}/Messages/{messageID}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const messageData = snap.data();
  const messageSender = messageData.fullName;

  // access the documentRef at collection level
  const chatRoomRef = snap.ref.parent.parent;

  // access the data at collection level
  const chatRoomSnap = await chatRoomRef.get();
  const chatRoomData = chatRoomSnap.data();
  const groupMembers = chatRoomData.members;
  const activeUsers = chatRoomData.activeUserStatus;
  const chatRoomTitle = chatRoomData.chatRoomTitle;
  const notificationTitle = `ChatRoom: ${chatRoomTitle}`
  const notificationBody = `${messageSender} sent a message`;

  groupMembers.forEach((item, i) => {

    const statusValue = activeUsers[item]

    if (statusValue == 0) {
      const topic = item.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-');

      const message = {
        notification : {
            title : notificationTitle,
            body: notificationBody
        },
        apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              sound : `default`
            }
          }
        },
        topic: topic,
      };
      // send notification subscribed to topic
      admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        console.log(`Successfully sent message to ${topic}`, response);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

The above is working in the emulator, see logs:

i  functions: Beginning execution of "australia-southeast1-newMessage"

i  functions: Finished "australia-southeast1-newMessage" in ~1s

Successfully sent message to 5-3-com projects/

Successfully sent message to 3-4-com projects/

When deployed into firestore, the logs in firestore functions show the function executing without any messages being sent to the topic.

7:53:04.745 am
newMessage
Function execution started

7:53:05.807 am
newMessage
Function execution took 1063 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

Comment: You're ignoring the promises returned by `admin.messaging().send().then.().catch()`.  It's not enough to just call then and catch.  You need to return a promise that resolves only after all async work is complete. That signals to Cloud Functions that it's safe to terminate the code.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be returning values, either a promise or a null value. If you need multiple promises to resolve, you can use `await Promise.all()` or use `.allSettled()` per your design.

What's also happening is since the `async` doesn't have anything to await or return, it'll finalize before resolving the `.then()` since it is `async`

This is because the Emulation is not a 1 to 1 comparison to Cloud Functions.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks!